# How to reformulate 'honor the data'

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-requests

I have written sentence like this

> The resulting property models from cooperative inversion honor the geophysical data

My Professor wants me to reformulate the sentence, in particular he raised a concern about *honor the data*. Physical property models produced by cooperative inversion are in accord with data.
How to do this?

Comment: We'll be able to help you better if you elaborate more on what you'd like to express with this entire sentence, and especially what you mean by *honor the data*. Can you [edit] your question to include these details, please?

Comment: An idiom of sorts I've heard a number of times is "follow the data" (presumably a twist on the detective story phrase "follow the evidence").

Comment: Your question seems to contain its own answer with "Physical property models produced by cooperative inversion are in accord with (the geophysical) data."

Comment: ... Is highly correlated with the data,  ... Has a correlation coefficient of <0.95> with the geophysical data.

Answer (score 2):

General:

> The resulting property models from cooperative inversion **are in accord with** the geophysical data.

or

> The resulting property models from cooperative inversion **reflect** the geophysical data.

Mathematical, geometry angle:

> The resulting property models from cooperative inversion **are congruent with** the geophysical data.

Mathematical, statistical angle (thank you, Jim):

> The resulting property models from cooperative inversion **are highly correlated with** the geophysical data (p<.05).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that the geophysical data was used to construct the property models, so I would suggest:

> The resulting property models from cooperative inversion **are based on**
>   the geophysical data

or

> The resulting property models from cooperative inversion **are
>   consistent with** the geophysical data

If you mean that the property models result from cooperative inversion, I would re-word it as follows:

> The property models resulting from cooperative inversion **are
>   consistent with** the geophysical data

or

> The property models resulting from cooperative inversion **are
>   based on** the geophysical data

If word-count isn't an issue, I would unpack the sentence even more, and explain how you got from the geophysical data to the property model in two separate sentences.

> The geophysical data was transformed through a series of cooperative
>   inversions. These were used to produce the property models.